# In what ways are the charges and surface charge densities distributed when two charged conducting spheres are connected?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

When two charged conducting solid spheres(having charges Q1 & Q2) are connected,the charges get distributed in the ratio of their capacitance(C).C∝radius in case of spheres and hence charge distributes in ratio of their radii.
What about the surface charge densities(σ)?
I think they will distribute in the opposite ratio of the radii[taking (Q1/Q2=R1/R2) and substituting Q=σ*4πR²]
Am I right?
Can this fact that Q∝R and σ∝1/R be generalised for conductors of any shape in contact?